# QGIS 3.8 - forest leaftype symbols

Tags: qgis, layers, overpass-api

I'm pulling forest data from OSM through overpass API to QGIS 3.8. Then I have a new layer with a simple fill (filled with color).

I would like to use the same symbols as in OSM instead of simple colors, example attached. Any ideas on how to achieve that?[image]

Comment: Have you even had a look at the symbology tab in the layers properties?

Comment: Yup, tried there, for "Single Symbol" I found for example "topo forest" or "topo swamp". I know that "Simple fill" can be changed to SVG fill, there is even a "symbol" group that contains something that looks like a forest but I'm keen to get the same symbols as in OSM which I couldn't find.

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Icons - first hit on google searching for OSM symbols

Comment: Ahh, now I see - there is a link to GIT repo and there are SVG for forest: https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/tree/master/symbols

Comment: @beribazoo - QGIS has some in-built SVG files of tree symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a github repository with all the symbols OSM uses, the following one of particular interest: https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/tree/master/symbols

The specific symbols can be found in the `generating patterns` folder and are titled `broadleaved.svg`, respectively `needleleaved.svg`.

Once downloaded and saved in a directory which is added as an SVG path to QGIS, the symbols can be added to a layers symbology. In this special usecase, it would be a `point pattern fill` with svg-symbols.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. Also just to expand a little, the specific symbols are in the 'generating_patterns' folder titled 'broadleaved.svg' and 'needleleaved.svg'. These would need to be downloaded and their directory added as an SVG path in QGIS and added to the symbology as Point Pattern Fills on top of the green background.